# Unable to find ant program

Tags: ant

I am an experienced (but retired) Windows software developer, with more years experience than I care to admit, developing in C++, C#, VB and Java. I therefore decided to have a crack at Android development. My development machine is a Windows 7 box. My IDE of choice would be Microsoft Visual Studio but, for now, I am happy doing hand editing and launching tools from the command line.

I started by downloading the Android SDK and various additional items it suggested. I then started working my way through the tutorial at developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp. Android list targets gave me a couple of choices (Android 4.2.2 and Google APIs:17). I then did Android create project from the command line and that appeared to do its stuff, creating MyFirstApp in my development folder. I then ran Android avd and created an emulator. I also added the android SDK's tools and platform-tools to my path. So far so good.

I fell at the next hurdle. The tutorial told me to change to the root folder of my project and run ant debug. At this point, Windows reports:
  'ant' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
  operable program or batch file.

I've searched around for ant.exe without success. Did I miss installing something or did I miss a vital step in the set-up? Any advice for this very green newbie would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: The only ant I'm familiar with is the build tool, Apache Ant. There's a .NET version of it available called nAnt.

Answer (score 0):

There is no `ant.exe`. Only `ant.bat`. Ant is a Java build tool.

If it comes with the Android SDK, make sure its `bin` directory is in your `PATH` environment variable. Otherwise, download it (from `[http://ant.apache.org][1]`), and follow the installation instructions on the web site.

Normally, simply unzipping it, putting its bin directory in the PATH envieonment variable, and setting a JAVA_HOME environment variable that points to your preferred JDK directory is sufficient.